# How to align the buffer address in a Linux block device

Tags: linux, driver, block

I am writing a block device driver for an embedded system. I am using a ram disk example to base my code on. I have tested the ram disk driver, but the buffer address it uses doesn't seem to be aligned, Below is an example

```
[25605.754145] rb: Sec: 991, Offset: 0; Buf: 00000000dab33acc; Len: 1 secnum
[25605.759566] rb: Sec: 992, Offset: 0; Buf: 000000009f16b8b1; Len: 8 secnum
[25605.759567] rb: Sec: 992, Offset: 8; Buf: 00000000bf688b1d; Len: 8 secnum
[25605.759568] rb: Sec: 992, Offset: 16; Buf: 000000003f34aef7; Len: 8 secnum
[25605.759569] rb: Sec: 992, Offset: 24; Buf: 000000009b7f0e8b; Len: 8 secnum
```

My hardware needs the buffer address to be aligned to 512 bytes. Can anyone tell me if its possible to do this, and if so how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Where do the allocations occur? If it is userland, use `posix_memalign`.

Comment: Its in the block driver code. I am guessing the Kernel must do the allocations.